# shortcut for System.out.print() in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Does Eclipse have a short cut for `System.out.print()` ?
I keep seeing `crtl+space` but this gives `System.out.println()` and its annoying to delete that `ln` part. I know its petty but I've needed to do it a lot so it might be useful to know.

I tried googling it but it only gives `ctrl+space` and does not go into the specifics. Thank you.

Comment: Add your own template for this in the preferences _Java > Editor > Templates_.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you must be using an older version of Eclipse.  I'm pretty sure "sysout" is installed by default.  This is what I see (at the page @howlger mentions):

[image: java editor templates]